# Solutions for sum in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm an absolute beginner to prolog. I've just read a basic tutorial and tried to solve a quick problem on my own. The problem is this, find possible number combinations that lead to a sum. I'm expecting something like this:

```
sum(A,B,11).
```

This should result in values for A and B that would sum them upto 10.

My initial code was this:

```
sum(A,B,C):-
    C is A + B.
```

But I do not get any results with this. I get the following.

```
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] 11 is _3302+_3304
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

What am I missing in my understanding of Prolog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This should result in values for A and B that would sum them upto 10.

If you consider negative numbers as well, there are infinite possible results: `.. -100+111, -2+13, -1+12, 0+11, 1+10, 2+9, 150+-139 ..`.

Your program will confirm the sum, and perform the calculation given the inputs for A and B:

```
?- sum(2,9,11).
true

?- sum(2,9,C).
C = 11
```

but even if you leave out one of them, it can't solve it.

```
?- sum(A,9,11).
is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

You are hoping Prolog will intuit that you mean "numbers between 0 and 11 which sum to 11" but Prolog sees a potentially infinite search space, and nowhere to start searching, and no way to narrow it down.

Paulo Moura's answer will generate the numbers in the range, and test them all, and show which pairs satisfy `A + B = C`. He mentions constraint solvers, which are libraries available for popular Prolog implementations and they have a more general way of solving problems like this. Constrain the solution space in some way ("A and B are positive integers"), as many constraints as you know, and then they apply those rules to reason about numbers, apply more techniques to find the answers without searching every imaginable number:

```
% load the 'clpfd' code
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

% define a sum using the imported #= instead of "is"
mysum(A, B, C) :-
    C #= A + B.


% declare that A and B are positive,
% and solve for A and B values.
?- mysum(A, B, 11), A in 0..sup, B in 0..sup, label([A,B]).
```

In this case it ends up being more code, but if you're generally hoping for Prolog to solve numeric calculations for you, you will likely have to go in this direction rather than using `between()` and making all the number lists yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Can you let me know why Prolog does not devolve into an infinite loop when processing queries like mine? It is my understanding that there is no general algorithm for the halting problem i.e. how does the program (the prolog compiler) know that the search space is infinitely large and any constraints I add make it not infinite?

Comment: @NikhilVandanapu Sorry, I'm too much of a beginner to be able to answer that. It doesn't solve the halting problem, there are situations where Prolog will loop forever. Alex Moura generates every number and makes a small search space, and tests each one. Constraint libraries must do a similar thing behind the scenes - they must start searching somewhere. But they allow you work at a higher level and bound the search space with things you know about it - "answers won't be here". CLP/FD knows more rules of arithmetic, than basic Prolog, too. But I don't understand how - it might be magic ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The standard `is/2` predicate requires an evaluable arithmetic expression for second argument. Thus, in your case, you will need to generate possible values for `A` and `B` so that `A + B` can be computed. To make it practical, you will need to restrict the range of possible values. For example:

```
?- between(1,7,A), between(1,7,B), sum(A,B,11).
A = 4,
B = 7 ;
A = 5,
B = 6 ;
A = 6,
B = 5 ;
A = 7,
B = 4 ;
false.
```

As you progress on your learning of Prolog, you may eventually be interested in learning about constraint solvers.